# How to redirect custom aspx page to mvc action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, nopcommerce

I have upgrade aspx project to mvc. Now some of my old customer calling url with .aspx page and they are getting 404(not found) in mvc project.

So now I have to redirect .aspx to mvc page.

Old URL

```
www.domain.com/bookshop/showproduct.aspx?isbn=978-1-59333-934-0
```

New URL

```
www.domain.com/{product_name}
```

I am thinking to do via routing mechanism of mvc. like once this type of url come then it should be call my custom mvc action and in string parameter i will get showproduct.aspx?isbn=978-1-59333-934-0

Can you please suggest a best way to do this with minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class RouteHandler as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Sample.Helpers
{
    public class RouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return new ASPDotNetHttpHandler();
        }
    }

    public class ASPDotNetHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string product = context.Request.QueryString["isbn"];
            int index = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("bookshop/showproduct.aspx?");

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(product) || index == -1))
            {
                string newUrl = context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, index)+"/" + product;
                context.Response.Redirect(newUrl, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Insert new route as shown below in RegisterRoutes method of RouteConfig.cs file:

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(new Route("bookshop/showproduct.aspx", new BIRS.Web.Helpers.RouteHandler()));
```